# Datepicker materialize disable day by time

Tags: datepicker, frontend, materialize

Hello i am new in frontEnd, can you help me with some issue, i have create a materialize datepicker and want to add function when is 12 AM to disable selected day? this is code :

```
M.Datepicker.init(Calendar, {
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    showClearBtn: true,
    disableWeekends: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: new Date(2020, 9, 1),
    i18n: {
        clear: 'Remove',
        done: 'Confirm'
    },`
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such option in that plugin to do so.

What I would do, is check before calling that plugin, that current time is before 12 AM.
If it is, I would display the datepicker, else, I would hide it and show message informing that.